# Why ListView Multiple Selection Model Updates Automatically

Tags: listview, javafx

I'm learning JavaFX `ListView` I want to know why the `listViewRight`'s items update automatically when I select the `listViewLeft`'s Item?

**FXML Code:**

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView ?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label ?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode ?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModel ?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox ?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections ?>
<?import java.lang.String ?>
<BorderPane prefWidth="600" prefHeight="250" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="ListViewController">
    <left>
        <ListView fx:id="listViewLeft" editable="true">
            <items>
                <FXCollections fx:id="collection" fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <String fx:value="Good" />
                    <String fx:value="Bad" />
                    <String fx:value="Average" />
                </FXCollections>
            </items>
        </ListView>
    </left>

    <right>
        <ListView fx:id="listViewRight" />
    </right>
</BorderPane>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;

public class ListViewController{
    @FXML private ListView<String> listViewLeft;
    @FXML private ObservableList<String> collections;
    @FXML private CheckBox newItem;
    @FXML private ListView<String> listViewRight;

    public void initialize(){
        collections = listViewLeft.getItems();
        listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);


        listViewRight.setItems(listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    }
}
```

When I select item from `listViewLeft` then that Item automatically show into the `listViewRight` why? I just called `listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` to add all selected items to the `listViewRight` why it `binds` to the `listViewRight` ?

Comment: Do you want to dynamically changethe __listViewRight__ items or do you just initially want to set the items to all, during the initialization, selected items from the __listViewLeft__?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The "backing list"

A `ListView` has a reference to an `ObservableList`, which you can access via `getItems()`; that `ObservableList` contains the elements which are displayed in the list view. The `ObservableList` is sometimes referred to as the `ListView`'s "backing list" (which I'll do here).

The `ListView` registers listeners with the backing list, so that if the contents of the list change, the list view is updated.

## Changing items in a `ListView` (two different ways)

There are two ways to change the items displayed by a `ListView`. You can either change the contents of the backing list. For example:

```
listView.getItems().setAll(someCollection);
```

will remove all the items currently in the backing list, and replace them with all the items in the supplied collection.

Alternatively, you can provide a new backing list entirely:

```
listView.setItems(someObservableList);
```

This will *tell the `ListView` to use `someObservableList` as its backing list*. It will remove any listeners it had registered with the current backing list, add listeners to the list you provide, and the contents of the list you provide will become the contents of the list view.

## Selected Items in a `ListView`

The selection model exposes an `ObservableList` containing the selected items in the list, via `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()`. The `ListView` updates this list automatically when the user selects or deselects items in the list view. Since this is an `ObservableList`, you can register listeners with it in order to be notified when its contents change, i.e. when items are selected or deselected.

## What your code does

So in the code you provided you do:

```
listViewRight.setItems(listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

This tells `listViewRight` to use the list of selected items from `listViewLeft` *as its backing list*. I.e. if the contents of `listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` change, then the contents of the `ListView` change: that's the purpose of a backing list.

On the other hand, if you had instead done

```
listViewRight.getItems().setAll(listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

you would have replaced the content of `listViewRight`'s current backing list with the selected items in `listViewLeft` (i.e. you would clear the backing list and copy the selected items in `listViewLeft` to the backing list). In this case subsequent changes to `listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` would not be reflected in the backing list of `listViewRight`.

Comment: How I can update the ListView's data in database when it changes? Mean suppose I change the row of List how I can update just that row in the databse? I know about the `onChanged(ListChangedListener.Change)` but how I can update that in database? Suppose I'm getting names from the database and showing them in ListView. and if I changed name A to B then how I can update that name in Database?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a read in the **ListView** JavaFX 8 Documentation from (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html). For your problem have a look at the following part:

> Populating a ListView
>
> A simple example of how to create and populate a ListView of names (Strings)  is shown here:

```
ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Julia", "Ian", "Sue", "Matthew", "Hannah", "Stephan", "Denise");
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>(names);
```

> The elements of the ListView are contained within the items ObservableList. This ObservableList is automatically observed by the ListView, such that any changes that occur inside the ObservableList will be automatically shown in the ListView itself. If passying the ObservableList in to the ListView constructor is not feasible, the recommended approach for setting the items is to simply call:

```
ObservableList<T> content = ...
listView.setItems(content);
```

> The end result of this is, as noted above, that the ListView will automatically refresh the view to represent the items in the list. 
>   Another approach, whilst accepted by the ListView, is not the recommended approach:

```
List<T> content = ...
getItems().setAll(content);
```

So what you're trying to to is the **not the recommended approach**. For you to test, change your code

```
listViewRight.setItems(listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

to

```
listViewRight.getItems().setAll(listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

Comment: I already read the documentation. I think you didn't read my question carefully. I'm talking about why listViewRight binds to ListViewLeft after calling `listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` ? Because once I select any item from the leftList that automatically show in the rightList.

Comment: @Nothing You're calling `setItems` with a `ObservableList` as argument. This makes sure any modification to this list will be propagated, i.e. a change of the selection of the left listview changes the items of the right... This does answer the question, even if it could be formulated better...

Comment: @fabian Feel free to help me - I would appreciate your commitment.

Comment: @SSchuette instead of quoting the javadoc it would be better to write this in your own words and not refer to something that you recommend here as the "not recommended approach". (BTW: of course you need to call `setAll` for the items list not the listview itself. Just fixed that issue in your answer.)

Comment: @fabian I know about that. But I confused how the rightListView's observableList getting notified from the leftListView? I'm expecting `listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` will return new ObservableList with selected Item after that it should not know about the listViewLeft.( after you comment I understand that `listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` is returning the same listViewLeft's `ObservableList`'s reference that is added to the listViewRight? that's why listViewLeft changes reflect to the ListViewRight because both are using same ObservableList?)

Comment: `listViewLedt` makes sure the items in the `ObservableList` returned by `listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` are the ones selected and that this list is kept up to date (Otherwise it wouldn't make sense to return a ***Observable***List). Passing the items to `listViewRight` using `setItems` makes sure the items of that listview are always those inside the list that you pass as parameter, i.e. the selection of the other listview...

Comment: Ok Let me explain what I understood. It is the responsibility of the listViewLeft that once any item is selected from the listViewLeft it will update that selected item to the listViewRight's ObservableList `( added by listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems() )` and then listViewRight will listen that change. Thanks. Let me know if I understand Wrong.

Comment: FWIW I think the documentation oversteps its bounds by calling `getItems().setAll(...)` "not the recommended approach". That call just has different functionality to `setItems(...)`, and the user should user whichever is appropriate for their requirements. @Nothing it looks like you have understood it now, but no-one has really pointed out that `listViewRight`'s `items` list is not *bound* to `listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()`: your code ensures `listViewRight`'s `items` list ***is*** `listViewLeft`'s `selectedItems` list. I.e. *they are the same list*.